# How to reference objects defined in another class?

Tags: objective-c

I had my iPhone app working, developed with Storyboard.  I decided to take all of the methods that belonged in a SQLite method and move them to a new SQLite class (.h and .m).

Now I have errors that I can't seem to get rid of.  The basic problem is the textfields on the "scene" are now unreachable from the SQLite class (they are in another class, where they belong).   The properties are defined in EDVController.m... I am trying to reach them from SQLite.m.

I have read the docs, but can't find anything that fits my problem.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why is your SQLite class trying to read UI properties directly? Why not have whatever class is responsible for the UI (maybe EDVController, depending on what that is) send the appropriate data to the SQLite class?

Comment: It's a half-dozen fields... EDVController.m has the fields defined because that's where  they are... they don't belong in any other class (kind of hard to explain, but the fields are in a view sitting in EDVController).

Comment: Then what's wrong with @JeremyRoman's suggestion? If there's a lot of fields, put all the field-data you need in a NSDictionary and send it to the SQLite class. You could also send `self` (i.e. EDVController-instance) to the SQLite class and reference the objects from there, but that's not a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give full credit to Jeremy Roman... I would up using NSMutableDictionary to pass the parameters, and it works like a champ!  Thank you Jeremy and Jia Yow.